# Access video after Authentication

Tags: video, coldfusion, web-config

I have a coldfusion application which can record video message and send to user. I want to make the videos private when user will view the video.

Like, if i hit example.com/test.mp4 url in the browser. it should authenticate that associated user is logged in site and viewing the video.

One thinking on which i was working is that, i must add web.config rewrite url which will rewrite all video url to a file and then that file will return video packet in response.

But i don't know how can i send back content in coldfusion. I can use cfcontent as follows

```
<cfheader name="Content-disposition" value="filename=test.mp4">
<cfcontent file="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Does any one know any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I did this a few years ago with a CF app. Instead of using cfcontent, I used Amazon Web Services. After checking the credentials with coldfusion, the server connected with AWS to get a token to load the mp4. With cflocation that token was passed to the client which then requested the mp4 from AWS with that token.

Sorry I don't have that project handy any more to get you the code. But at least you get the idea... check out AWS and secure access of files.